# Access to conda kernels in jupyter notebook keeps disappearing

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

Previously, i have accessed conda environments from within jupyter notebook by installing nb_conda_kernels in the base environment and ipykernel in my other environments. Recently, it has stopped working.

Making changes in the jupyter config file, uninstalling and reinstalling nb_conda and nb_conda kernels all fix the issue for a very short period of time, however a few minutes of not using jupyter immediately causes the conda kernels to disappear. The changes made in the config file still remain. I have even tried reinstalling Anaconda but all in vain. Please help!

Note: The kernels work fine on VS Code

Comment: Needs more details. E.g., versions of the `jupyter`, `nb_conda_kernels`, etc.